# Weird issue when running Python code with data-science libraries

Tags: python, matplotlib, import, anaconda, nltk

I use Python data science libraries like Pandas, Matplotlib, Numpy. I like working with these. And for ease of use, I also have Anaconda installed which makes creating environments a breeze. But today when running some matplotlib code I face a really weird issue that I didn't encounter ever before. This issue occurs right when I try to import Pyplot.

```sh
$ python
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

!▓KH═⌐-▌ª╚E├╚Hü⌠>┴┘UÜWF♀ε½░±-Sz;½¼öC¿Æ→$√
)ì⌠┐→⌐V¿U!└φÑ^~π┘╠⌡╗♦{ò►ßq╢ê<_│☺♀àV╣oY}ër╡╫╞╟lBîyû,πƒ=♂▒-Öδbùh♂RΣ}Ω¼╘zâ╫♫┘▀\φ→H
$Æ⌡«ε╖@{╤╧↕ƒÅ▄\.╔~s)╥τ♣E:,-Ut⌠↓R↑J¬τpg┐±`&╟╡▓  ▓û
TS1Å`a↑╚+╬╚?└D¿e£▀z¼i♥☼·s&⌐
```

When I try to import Pyplot I hear three dots (like morse code) and then this gibberish comes up and my program ends. I have never seen anything like this before.

It didn't give me any `ModuleNotFoundError` or any sort of errors at all. The program just literally stops and the gibberish is printed. I have copied exactly what gets printed.

I have encountered this issue with Matplotlib and also NLTK. Trying to import NLTK shows the same error. I don't know if this issue occurs with any other library but I can confirm it occurs with Matplotlib and NLTK.

I was thinking about re-installing Anaconda but was curious to know more about this really weird issue. I would also like to say that the issue is with my base (root) conda environment, NLTK doesn't have any issues in my other machine-learning environment. Any help is absolutely appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to turn what on or off??

Comment: Is the system using a different display language out of English?